# I am web-scraping for product and prices. The output is coming out with characters in between the product and prices how do i remove them

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("**website name**")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
books = soup.find('div',{'class':'row justify-content-md-first'})
#print(books)
items = books.find_all(class_='col-12')

#print(items[0].find(class_ ='product_title').get_text())
#print(items[0].find(class_ ='product_price').get_text())

product_titles = [item.find(class_ = 'product_title').get_text() for item in items]
product_prices = [item.find(class_ = 'product_price').get_text() for item in items]
print(product_titles)
#print(product_prices)

product_list = pd.DataFrame(
    {'product_title':product_titles,
    'product_price': product_prices,
    })

print(product_list)

product_list.to_csv('Product.csv')
```

---

```
                                        product_title                                  product_price
0   \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAlphabet Dot–To–Dot – ...   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR65.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
1   \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAlphabet Games and Puz...   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR65.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
2   \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAlphabet Hidden Pictur...   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR65.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
3   \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAmazing Mazes – Ages 4...   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR65.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
4   \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEarly Maths – Ages 4–5...   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR65.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
5   \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEarly Reading – Ages 4...   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR65.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
6   \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLearning Centres – Sel...  \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR210.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
7   \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLetters and Sounds – A...   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR65.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
8   \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNumbers Dot–To–Dot – A...   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR64.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
9   \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNumbers Fun – Ages 4–5...   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR65.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
10  \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNumbers Hidden Picture...   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR65.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
11  \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPatterns and Sequence ...   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR65.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
12  \n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTracing and Cutting – ...   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tR64.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) to remove leading and trailing characters.

```py
product_list = product_list.apply(lambda col: col.str.strip())
```

Comment: Where would I place it on the code. I have never used lambada

Comment: @coja56 After `print(product_list)` or before it.